# How to move messages.properties files into a separate folder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, localization

Is it possible to place **messages.properties** and all other locale-specific **messages_xx.properties** files in a sub-folder of the *resources* folder in a Spring Boot application?
For example to move them all in *langs* folder:

```
───  src
   └───  main
       ├───  java
       └───  resources
           ├───  langs
           │   ├─── messages.properties
           │   └─── messages_fa.properties
           └─── ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You just need to add this property in the `application.properties` or `application.yml` file:

```
spring.messages.basename=langs.messages
```

Here *langs* is the name of the folder and *messages* is the base name of files.

Comment: It is valid for `langs/messages` too. And even is possible change the expected file name how it is represented as the last term of the value, for example `langs.mensajes` or `langs/mensajes` ... IMHO is better use `/` in the path